# How to create a annual raster stack from MODIS-8 day LST product?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, rasterstack

This is a working code for generating a monthly raster stack from the MODIS 8-Day LST product. How to transform this code to create a similar annual raster stack for the same time period.

```
var interval = 1;
var month_list = ee.List.sequence(1,12, interval);
var year_list = ee.List.sequence(2000, 2020);
var moLST= ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A2")
                              .select('LST_Day_1km')
                              .filterBounds(India);
                              
                            
// Scale to Kelvin and convert to Celsius, set image acquisition time.
var LSTCollection= moLST.map(function(img) {
  return img
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
});
//Map.addLayer(LSTCollection.median().clip(India), {}, 'MODISLST'); 

var monthlyLST =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  year_list.map(function (ynz) {
  return month_list.map(function(mnz){
  var w = LSTCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(ynz, ynz, 'year'))
                        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(mnz, ee.Number(mnz).add(interval), 'month'))
                        .mean();
  return w.set('year', ynz)
                        .set('month', mnz)
                        .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(ynz,mnz,1))
                        .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(ynz,mnz,1).millis())
                        .set('ID',ee.Date.fromYMD(ynz,mnz,1))

})
}).flatten());

var LST = monthlyLST.toBands();

var LandsufTemp = LST.clip(India);

print(LandsufTemp, 'LST_India');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply remove the inner `month_list.map()`. You can skip setting the properties on `w`, since you lose them when calling `toBands()` in any case.

```
var annualLST = ee.ImageCollection
  .fromImages(
    year_list.map(function(ynz) {
      return LSTCollection
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(ynz, ynz, 'year'))
        .mean()
    })
  )
  .toBands()
  .rename(year_list.map(function(year) {
    return ee.Number(year).format('%d')
  })) // Name the band after the year
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8dc1165d15fdc81c6a12491ae1b1d27